# I have multiple ImageViews; Why cant I reference the ImageViews from a separate class into the main class?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to Reference Image Views that I declared in a separate class. When I call the class I get a null pointer exception.

```
    public int randomMeat(int choice)
    {
        Meats meats = new Meats();

        Random random = new Random();

        choice = random.nextInt(6-0+1)+1;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            default:
                meats.pepperoniIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 2:
                meats.baconIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 3:
                meats.beefIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 4:
                meats.chickenIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 5:
                meats.hamIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 6:
                meats.meatballIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
            case 7:
                meats.sausageIV.animate();
                System.out.println(choice);
                return choice;
        }
    }
```

'meats' is the separate class.

```
public class Meats extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Context context = this;

    //Reg
    ImageView pepperoniIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pepperoniIV);

    ImageView baconIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.baconIV);
    ImageView beefIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.beefIV);
    ImageView chickenIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chickenIV);
    ImageView hamIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hamIV);
    ImageView meatballIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.meatballIV);
    ImageView sausageIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sausageIV);
}
```

The Exception reads exactly

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference"

I'm not really sure why this is happening and could really use some help, Thanks!

Comment: Don't new a activity by `Meats meats = new Meats();` You should use `startActivity` to create Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you should not create an Activity yourself (as others have correctly noted - `Meats meats = new Meats();` will not work), you cannot call `findViewById` until `onCreate`, after you have called `setContentView`. Even if your activity was created correctly, it will still return null for all those `ImageView` members. It should look something more like this:

```
ImageView pepperoniIV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pepperoniIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pepperoniIV);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it did just as I wanted once implemented!

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` is a special class in the android system, we should instantiate it via [startActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) or other proper methods. Otherwise, we can not get the info of `context`.